# Magento Real Time product price update

Tags: price

I am working on a jewelry shop, and as we all know that Gold prices fluctuate every day so is there any way to address this matter?
Is there any way to update product prices based on gold rate in real time or at least once in a day?

Please help, any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Sure, what you can do is run a cronjob script. that call's the api for price updates. via

PUT /V1/products/{sku}
and then PUT your price to it.

With that cronjob script you can fetch gold prices from several services.